# How to authorize all users with different tokens using jwt in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, authorization

I have a node.js app. I'm using Json Web Token for authorization. When I Login with a user who is in my database, it creates a token for the user. But I can use that token for another user and it works too again. I need to have different tokens for all users and I should not use one user's token for another user. (I dont have internet on my work pc so I cant write my codes on my computer here sorry about that)

Here is my verify-token.js (middleware):

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, "secret_key");
    req.userData = decodedToken;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      message: "Auth failed"
    });
  }
};
```

And here is my login code (im creating the token here)
if password is true:

```
const token = jwt.sign(
  {
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  },
  "secret_key",
  {
    expiresIn: "2h"
  }
);

return res.status(200).send({ message: "success", token: token });
```

And in app.js:

```
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/checkauth');
router.get('/api/company',checkAuth,companyController.list);
```

I expect that one token should be for just one user, and  for every login it should creates a new token for all users. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you open it more please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including the email in your token body; why not also include the user ID as a claim (field)? When you verify the token, if it's successful, it will return the body to you, so then you'll know which user that token was made for and reject if it's not the one who's making the request.

To ensure two people don't use the same token at the same time, you can keep a list of every valid token when you generate it, and when a token expires or is revoked (for instance, when the user signs out or reports an imposter, if it gets that far) remove it from the list. During verification, if the token is not on the list, don't even bother decoding it, just reject it immediately.

If you give your tokens decently small expiration windows (I believe the recommendation is to make them last no longer than 1 hour), you shouldn't have to worry about such things much.

**EDIT** To clarify, you'll never have a way to know for sure that the person who gave you the token is who they claim to be. You only know if your server created the token and if the token is currently valid. If you really want to prevent replay attacks (that is, make absolutely sure there's no way for two people to use the same token at once), you'll need to generate a new token every time one is used. If you keep that whitelist that I mentioned above, this regeneration ensures every token becomes invalid as soon as it's used once.

You can also, to be EXTRA confident, include a `jti` claim in the token body; this is a field intended to be filled with a random unique value every time a token is generated, so that you can keep track of the jti's you've received and not allow the same one to come in more than once. It's about the same as just keeping track of the tokens, though.

Comment: `reject if it's not the one who's making the request` how you will know which user is making the request?

Comment: You don't. Passport-JWT doesn't even have a way to verify that (check the example code for Passport-JWT: they're just checking if the user in the payload exists in a Mongo database and, if so, considering it verified.) There's no way to know that the person sending the token is the person they claim to be; that's the basis of replay attacks. The closest option is to re-sign a new token every time one is used rather than having just an expiration date. I'll add that to the answer just now.

Comment: my question here is not related to Passport-JWT. however i agree with that.

Comment: Right; my answer to your question was simply "you don't". I just went on to talk about Passport-JWT to emphasize the point that not even the standard libraries can answer that question :)